# Why is it that some user defined C++ functions won't work with big numbers?

Tags: c++, c, computer-science

Here's an example:

This function won't work with big numbers such as 900000000 but will work with smaller numbers like 800

code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string> using namespace std;


long long int largest_prime_factor(long long int num){
    vector<long long int >factors;
    vector<long long int>primes;
    for(long long int i=1;i<=num;i++){
        if(num%i==0){
            for(long long int a =1;a<=i;a++){
                if(i%a==0){
                    factors.push_back(a);
                }

            }
            if( (factors.size() == 2) && (factors[0] ==1)){
                primes.push_back(i);
            }
            factors.clear();
        }
    }
    reverse(primes.begin(),primes.end());
    return primes[0]; }

int main(){
    cout<<largest_prime_factor(600851475143)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: It looks like it'll take ages to complete (so many prime number tests...). You should probably try a different approach. Hint: If a number x can be factorised as y * z, then the largest prime factor of x is the larger of the largest prime factors of y and z.

Comment: @Wintermute is correct. I ran your code 10 minutes ago (still running), clogging a core. btw, you can also start from sqrt(num) down instead of from 1 up - since you're looking for **largest** prime factor - and break the non prime factors as Wintermute suggests.

Comment: I'd still run up from 1 (well, from 2). The point is: When you find a factor x that divides num, you don't have to run up to num anymore but only to num / x. The largest prime factor is going to be either the largest prime factor of x or the largest prime factor of num / x. More hints: This can be done in a way that ensures that x is prime. The smallest factor > 1 of any natural number is prime (if it exists).

Comment: You've done a very literal implementation of "a prime number is a number with only two divisors, 1 and itself". You don't need to find *all* the divisors to determine whether there are any more than those - you only need to find one of them.

Comment: "Won't work" - what do you get and what did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking the function with the following code:

```
cout<<largest_prime_factor(600851475143LL)<<endl;
```

If you simply mention the literal 600851475143, it wont be recognized as long long. you have to explicitly tell the compiler that treat the literal as long long by appending 'LL' at the end.

Comment: That's not true in C++ (see [lex.icon]/2; a decimal integer literal without a suffix has the smallest signed integer type into which its value fits).